# Error: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Tags: python, numpy

I defined `u` and `v`

```
u = np.array([[1],
              [1]])

v = np.array([[1],
              [-1]])
```

and i want to find `A`

```
Au = np.array([[3],
               [2]])
Av = np.array([[-1],
               [-2]])
```

so i coded like this

```
A = np.linalg.solve(u,Au)
A = np.linalg.solve(v,Av)
print(A)
```

and then i got error

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-416fc4de15b6> in <module>
     12                [-2]])
     13 
---> 14 A = np.linalg.solve(u,Au)
     15 A = np.linalg.solve(v,Av)
     16 print(A)

    <__array_function__ internals> in solve(*args, **kwargs)
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in solve(a, b)
        384     a, _ = _makearray(a)
        385     _assert_stacked_2d(a)
    --> 386     _assert_stacked_square(a)
        387     b, wrap = _makearray(b)
        388     t, result_t = _commonType(a, b)
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in _assert_stacked_square(*arrays)
        211         m, n = a.shape[-2:]
        212         if m != n:
    --> 213             raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')
        214 
        215 def _assert_finite(*arrays):
    
    LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: see the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy-linalg-solve). `np.linalg.solve(a, b)` in this "If a is singular or not square" it raises `LinAlgError`

Comment: `np.linalg.solve` solves for x in equaitons lookin like Ax = y, where A is a matrix and x and y are vectors (possibly vertically stacked into matrices. You seem to want to find A. That cannot really be done, as there is not a unique A to give this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `A` is the same in both equations, you have got 4 equations with 4 unknowns:

```py
A[0, 0] * u[0] + A[0][1] * u[1] = Au[0]
A[1, 0] * u[0] + A[1][1] * u[1] = Au[1]
A[0, 0] * v[0] + A[0][1] * v[1] = Av[0]
A[1, 0] * v[0] + A[1][1] * v[1] = Av[1]
```

This can be rephrased as a matrix equation `B a = Auv` where

- `a` are the values of `A` in a vector
- `Auv` are the concatenated vectors `Au` and `Av`,
- `B` contains the values of `u` and `v`.

```py
import numpy as np

u = [1, 1]
v = [1, -1]
Au = [3, 2]
Av = [-1, -2]
B = [
    [u[0], u[1], 0, 0],
    [0, 0, u[0], u[1]],
    [v[0], v[1], 0, 0],
    [0, 0, v[0], v[1]]]

Auv = np.concatenate([Au, Av])

A = np.linalg.solve(B, Auv).reshape(2, 2)

print("A:\n", A)
```

The matrix `A` is:

```
1 2
0 2
```